# How to render arc_ecto image in Phoenix framework template?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I written below code in my template.

`<img src="<%= EdgeEc.Photo.url({@image.content, @image}, :original) %>" alt="" />`

This is rendered like below.

`<img src="uploads/large_myimagefilename.jpg.jpg?v=63615301283" alt="" />`

Then, I typed the path `localhost:4000/uploads/large_116.jpg.jpg?v=63615301283` in address bar and got below error.

`no route found for GET /uploads/large_116.jpg.jpg (EdgeEc.Router)`

Perhaps, because uploaded image is not model and it's not have routed controller.

Can I route uploaded images and rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self solved.

I found below issue.

https://github.com/stavro/arc_ecto/issues/4

Answer (score 1):

Or, in more detail, you want to serve [static assets](http://www.phoenixframework.org/v0.10.0/docs/static-assets). I actually found that *modifying* the existing `plug` is the only thing that works, so, if your app name like in your example is EdgeEc:

In your `lib/edge_ec/endpoint.ex`:

```
plug Plug.Static,
  at: "/", from: :edge_ec,
  only: ~w(css fonts images js uploads favicon.ico robots.txt)
```

Also make sure your arc file module definition's storage directory starts with `priv/static`:

```
def storage_dir(_version, {_file, _scope}), do: "priv/static/uploads"
```

And write a helper for the URL generator to trim the `priv/static`:

```
def photo_url(struct) do
  Photo.url({struct.image, struct})
  |> Path.relative_to("priv/static")
end
```